# Stop setInterval() when Component Unmounts? (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, intervals

I am looking to stop an interval function when a user on my website changes the page. I searched online for "how to tell if a react element is visible on the screen," but I can only find results for intersection observers. Is there a way to stop an interval function when a react component dismounts? (ps. I believe dismounting is when the component is no longer rendered?)

Heres my component interval:

```
useEffect(() => {
   const updatePostInfo =
     inView &&
      setInterval(() => {
        dispatch(getPostInfo(data._id));
  }, 3500);
!inView && clearInterval(updatePostInfo);
}, [inView]);
```

Currently, I have it set up with an intersection observer so that it doesn't dispatch the function when it isn't visible. But the interval still runs when the page changes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to return a cleanup function from your effect:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const updatePostInfo = setInterval(() => {
    dispatch(getPostInfo(data._id));
  }, 3500);
  return () => clearInterval(updatePostInfo);
}, []);
```